# Angular dependencies on simple functions/objects

Tags: angularjs

Angular modules can be depending on other modules. Angular controllers can be dependent on services.

But what if one of my modules/controllers is depending on a non-angular function or object? Should I wrap it inside an Angular factory, thus making it "official"? Should I include it in the HTML as script and not tell anything about it in my module at all, simply hoping for it being available in global scope?

What is the usual pattern in such cases?

Comment: Just wrap it inside a service or factory imo, just for the sake of consistent and best practice.

Comment: We usually wrap them in Service, link function of directive etc. For wrapping 3rd party js into angular service, checkout example for using Google Places API example for angular), For directives check including highcharts in angularjs.

Comment: Service most definitely